# jQuery Ajax: Cannot highlight text from ajax result

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to display all employee name from database and automatically display the newly added name without page refresh. I used **setInterval** to get the data every 1 second so the displayed data is always updated.

My problem is, I cannot highlight a text from the ajax result because it refresh the ajax result every 1 second. So how can I be able to do that?

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url+'dashboard/getLastPost',
        success: function(data) {
            $('.lastPost').html(data);
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: lets say you have <h2 class="highlight">User</h2>, and it is coming from ajax response every time. Can you still not highlight it?

Comment: Every second seems a bit often? If you have to get the data in that short intervals, redesign the system to just return the new names, and add those to the list, instead of replacing everything.

Comment: Actually I can highlight it from ajax response, but I am using setInterval, when I highlight a text, the ajax response refresh every x second because of setInterval and it affects the highlight text. ahhmmm thanks I need to redesign it, you mean I only need to append the newly added names?

Comment: What do you mean by highlight?  Do you mean show it selected or just a show a background color? You can use a CSS style to set background color.  If you want it to show as selected text, you have to reselect the text each time after you set new text because you've destroyed the previous selection.

Comment: I just want to highlight and copy text from ajax result.

Comment: Do you mean "highlight", as in selecting a text range with the mouse or keyboard, that can be copied etc. and that selection is lost when the data is removed and replaced with new data every second? If so, see my last comment, the best thing would be to not replace everything, but just add the new content.

Comment: for example facebook, everytime the users post a status, not just 1 user, it automatically display in new feeds, and everyone can copy the text. @adeneo, yes you are right. Im just getting confuse.

Comment: Like adeneo said, every 1 second is fairly extreme. I bet your ajax call isnt even completing in that time which will cause them to start to back up in queue pretty quickly. Not to mention, there's never a guarantee that the first call will return first which could lead to nasty bugs later with miss-ordered comments

Comment: how many seconds should I set? I just made it every 10seconds and everytime a user add a status it prepends while fetching other new status .. so It dont need to load all posts, just new posts.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
success: function(data) {
            $('.lastPost').css("color","red");
            $('.lastPost').html(data);
        }
```